# select specific row php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I know its sounds like repeated but really I didn't find an answer for the problem am having.

am making a form to get specific details which is password
this is the form

```
<form method="post" name="lostpass" action="forgotpass.php">
                        <ul>
                        <li>Admin Name:<input name="admin" type="text"></li>
                        <li> E.mail: <input name="email" type="text"><br></li>  
                        </ul>
                        <input type="submit" name="get" value="get infos">
                        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
                    </form>
```

so from it this data I get I can get the lost password

and this is the php codes

```
 <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("rock","mido","1234","fyp");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT password FROM admin WHERE email = 'email', Admin = 'admin' ");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

    echo  $row['password'];

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

its giving me this error (mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result).

thanx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this code :

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT password FROM admin WHERE email = 'email', Admin = 'admin' ");
```

with

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT password FROM admin WHERE email = '$_POST[email]' AND Admin = '$_POST[admin]'");
```

Thanks.

Comment: do u have any idea how to make the result or the echo on popup window ?

Comment: Do you want like this :echo "<script>alert('Hellow Muhammad Ashikuzzaman Odesk Password of your ID Has been Changed!');</script>";

Comment: almost. I want it to show the password stored in the database ..
somehow like a massage says : your password is: 12345678

Comment: Please describe the problem again.

Comment: I did like this but it didn't work echo "<script>alert("<?php echo "your password is:" . "$row['password']"?>") </script>"

Comment: You can't put double quote between another double quote. Try with this    ............?> <script>alert("<?php echo 'your password is:' . '$row[password]'?>") </script> <?php ...........  . Better you ask another question and i am answering there.